# How to Increase Matplotlib Basemap Size?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

How can I increase the size of the basemap?  It is small compared to the size of the accompanying color bar. My basemap includes the geographic locations that I want, it is just physically too small.  Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide

Comment: Are you using an interactive backend?

Comment: can you post some sample code that we can modify?

Answer (score 16):

One possibilty is to call `plt.figure(figsize=(WIDTH, HEIGHT))` before you call any of the drawing methods of your map object, like so:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
map = Basemap()
map.drawcoastlines()
map.plot()
```